# PickerViewにデフォルト値を設定できない

Tags: swift, uipickerview

`PickerView`の最初に選択されている値を取得してデータベースに格納しようとしているのですが、データ登録後にデータベースを確認すると中身が空になってしまっています。
また、この`ViewController`から他の`ViewController`へ移動しようとすると、「`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`」というエラーがログに出力されてアプリが落ちてしまいます。
いまいちまだオプショナル型についても分かってないので、詰まってしまいました。
どうすれば`PickerView`の初期値を取得して正常に動かすことができるでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var speechPicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var dataForSpeechPicker = ["A", "B", "C"]
    var registerWordStore = ""
    var registerSpeechStore = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        speechPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK:- picker

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerview1: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerview1: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return dataForSpeechPicker.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return dataForSpeechPicker[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerview1: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        registerSpeechStore = dataForSpeechPicker[row]
    }

    // MARK:- textField

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool{
        registerWordStore = textField.text

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    // MARK:- registerButton

    @IBAction func registerWord(sender: AnyObject) {
        //データベース登録処理
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

初めまして。
そのエラーはnilの値をアンラップしようとした際に出るエラーです。

つまりnilなのに強制的にOptionalから型を戻そうとしている感じです。
通常の型はnilを扱えないのでこのようなエラーがでます。

値についてですが、delegateがないのでコールバックが呼ばれていないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 初めまして。ご回答ありがとうございます。
つまり@IBOutlet weak var speechPicker: UIPickerView!には何も値が入っていないということでしょうか？
現在delegateはstoryboardで設定しています。実際ピッカーを一回でも動かすと、ちゃんと値を取得することができました。

Comment: Pickerを一度でも動かすと値を取得できるとの事ですのでspeechPickerはnilなのではないと思います。
初期値の取得方法ですが、var position = 0みたいに現在のpositionを
viewDidLoadあたりで定義しておいて、動かされたら更新するように
しておけばposition指定で値取れると思います。
これなら初期値もposition指定で取得できます。

Comment: ご提示の方法のように初期値を設定することで値を取得することができました。誠にありがとうございました。